# Handle syntax errors in LuaInterface

Tags: c#, error-handling, lua, syntax-error, luainterface

I am trying to integrate a Lua Scripting interface into my C# project by using [LuaInterface](http://code.google.com/p/luainterface/).

It works as expected if I execute syntactically correct code, but as soon as a syntax error (or any other error as it seems) is introduced to the script an `SEHException` gets thrown without any information regarding the error.

A simple example to trigger the behavior: `new LuaInterface.Lua().DoString("die");`

That of course completely nullifies Lua's error handling mechanisms and is a show-stopper for me.

Apparently this is a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/luainterface/issues/detail?id=38) which is open since 2011.

Are there any workarounds, a version of LuaInterface without this bug or is there an alternative lua wrapper which correctly handles errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua errors (syntax or runtime errors) encountered by `DoString` should result in a `LuaException` being thrown. Its message will contain the error string generated by Lua. For instance, given your example:

```
try
{
    new LuaInterface.Lua().DoString("die");
}
catch (LuaException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

You should get the following error:

```
[string "chunk"]:1: '=' expected near '<eof>'
```

You don't show any context for your one liner. Is it wrapped in a try-catch block?

If so, perhaps it's [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/luainterface/issues/detail?id=38)?

Comment: My one-liner is not wrapped in a try-catch block. Even if I do wrap it, the exception is still an SEHException, not a LuaException, so it doesn't get thrown. Apparently it is a bug. Now the question remains: How to work around it?

Comment: Alright, I disabled Debugging-Break when Exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundary and that made it work. It is not pretty, but whatever.